# Determine order of specific substrings in string via regex

Tags: c#, regex

I wasn't able to find answer for my question anywhere. What is my problem?
I'll get a string which is composed out of 6 elements in "some order". For example elements could be: `date, ip, name, numberOfSomething >= 10, "nameOfMother" and digit`. Each element is some string, some ip, etc. I need to save order of these elements in which they are occuring in an input. A also need to save each element in some variable. Is there an easy way of doing this with regex?

input: `Maria 1.1.1.1 15/4/2020 124 "Ann" 6`

order: `[name, ip, date, numberOfSomething, "nameOfMother", digit]`

name:`"Maria"`, ip: `"1.1.1.1"`, ..., digit: `"6"`

I just need some idea or principle, full code shouldn't be necessary, just snippets should be fine. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some code you already tried and show where you failed. This will help you get an answer for your question.

Comment: I just made a class where I'll be saving those data, I wasn't able to write any regex because I have no idea how use it when order is not known and my goal is to determine the order. Everywhere they write about using regex to match something.

Comment: if you want pure Regex, you should write 6*5*4*3*2*1 regexes........

Answer (score 0):

This is my logic which I have illustrated in Node.JS. You can easily adapt this to C#.

```js
const input = 'Maria 1.1.1.1 15/4/2020 124 "Ann" 6';

const regexList = {
  name: /[A-Z][a-z]*/,
  digit: /(?<!\S)\d(?!\S)/,
  numberOfSomething: /(?<!\S)\d{2,}(?!\S)/,
  ip: /\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/,
  date: /([1-9]|[1-3][0-9])\/([1][0-2]|[1-9])\/\d{1,4}/,
  nameOfMother: /".+"/,
};

const results = [];
const resultsOrder = [];
const resultsName = {};

for ([key, value] of Object.entries(regexList)) {
  const match = value.exec(input);
  if (match) {
    results.push({
      name: key,
      value: match[0],
      index: match.index
    });
  }
}

results
  .sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index)
  .forEach(({
    name,
    value
  }) => {
    resultsName[name] = value;
    resultsOrder.push(value);
  });

console.log('Results: ', resultsName);
console.log('Order: ', resultsOrder);
```